# Uploading a static project to google app engines

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, google-app-engine

Disclaimer: I already asked [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/65361), but apparently off-topic.

I want to set up a page using [this](http://startbootstrap.com/modern-business) bootstrap template and host it as a static website using the google appengine service.

Inside the google_appengine directory, I created a folder *page* with the page data and the *app.yaml*:

- google_appengine [folder]
- ...
- dev_appserver.py
- appcfg.py
- ...
- page [folder]

  - app.yaml
  - public [folder]

app.yaml has this as a content:

```yaml
          application: coolmoon
      version: 1
      runtime: python27
      api_version: 1
      threadsafe: yes
    
      handlers:
    
      - url: /(.+)
        static_files: public/\1
        upload: public/(.*)
    
      - url: /
        static_files: public/index.html
        upload: public/index.html
    
      skip_files:
      - ^(.*/)?app\.yaml
      - ^(.*/)?app\.yml
      - ^(.*/)?#.*#
      - ^(.*/)?.*~
      - ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]
      - ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*
      - ^(.*/)?\..*
      - ^(.*/)?tests$
      - ^(.*/)?test$
      - ^test/(.*/)?
      - ^COPYING.LESSER
      - ^README\..*
      - \.gitignore
      - ^\.git/.*
      - \.*\.lint$
      - ^fabfile\.py
      - ^testrunner\.py
      - ^grunt\.js
      - ^node_modules/(.*/)?
```

When I'm inside the google_appengine folder and I run

```
python dev_appserver.py page
```

I get the error message

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "dev_appserver.py", line 82,
 in <module>
     _run_file(__file__, globals())   File "dev_appserver.py", line 78, in _run_file
     execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)   File "/home/bogus/webpage/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py",
 line 943, in <module>
     main()   File "/home/bogus/webpage/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py",
 line 936, in main
     dev_server.start(options)   File "/home/bogus/webpage/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py",
 line 695, in start
     options.config_paths)   File "/home/bogus/webpage/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py",
 line 617, in __init__
     config_paths = self._config_files_from_paths(config_paths)   File "/home/bogus/webpage/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py",
 line 682, in _config_files_from_paths
     self._config_files_from_dir(path) if os.path.isdir(path) else [path])   File
 "/home/bogus/webpage/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py",
 line 710, in _config_files_from_dir
     (dir_path, or_web_inf)) google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.errors.AppConfigNotFoundError:
 "page/" is a directory but does not contain app.yaml or app.yml
```

but app.yaml is definitely inside the folder *page*

What is going wrong?

Is my command correct?

Comment: "Inside the google_appengine directory" why would you? and what is "dev_appserver.py" doing in your project directory?

Comment: I consider the page folder as my project directory. The page folder is inside the google_appengine directory. This also seems to be the case in question 18554364

Comment: Well google_appengine tools ideally be on your PATH so that you can use them I doubt nesting your project in AppEngine tools is the best idea. I would look closely for modules name conflicts then.

Comment: I moved the page folder out of the google_appengine dir. Now, when I say  python dev_appserver.py ../page I still get the same error. The folder structure was meant to be shown in the bulletpoint list

Comment: Just a guess, I have not tested it, but I would imagine that The "skip_files element specifies which files in the application directory are not to be uploaded to App Engine" in which case I would drop both patterns for yaml files.

Comment: done. still the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57234/discussion-between-matcheek-and-bogus).

Comment: if you only want to serve static files as a website then this might be of interest: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration

Comment: I think this would give a different error, but make sure you have an `__init__.py` in your project directory, alongside `app.yaml`

Comment: I removed the entire skip_files paragraph, now I can at least see the page at http://localhost:11080/

Comment: Hope that application: coolmoon doesn't have that many spaces before it. If it does, remove them :)

Comment: Apart from solving your particular problem, have a look at any appengine starter projects like [gae-init](https://gae-init.appspot.com/) and go through the detailed tutorials where a lot of parts about the setup are being explained. I am guessing there are other misconfigurations too apart from the code inside the server.

Comment: Did anyone found the solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Amazon S3 or a similar service? It is more geared towards this sort of thing.