# Project Directory Does Not Contain app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm following the instructions here https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine

I've downloaded and unzipped the project file from that page - it's the python and flask one. When I get to the instruction `dev_appserver.py appending-try-python-flask` it gives the error.

```
google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.errors.AppConfigNotFoundError: "." is a directory but does not contain app.yaml or app.yml
```

It most certainly does contain an app.yaml file. It looks like this.

```
application: hello-flask-app-engine
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
- name: markupsafe
  version: "0.15"
```

Unlike this post [Uploading a static project to google app engines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725574/uploading-a-static-project-to-google-app-engines) mine doesn't have any skip files lines to delete.

There is a README.md that mostly follows the Google Dev web page, except that instead of downloading the project from that page it instructs to `git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-flask-skeleton.git` and that doesn't exactly match the zip file I downloaded.

The requirement.txt file says `Run 'pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib/'` but Windows 7 says pip is not a recognized command.

Is my app.yaml not correct? Why would it say it doesn't exist?

Comment: Try to run it like this: `dev_appserver.py appending-try-python-flask/app.yaml` (give the full path to the app.yaml file)

Comment: this works @DmytroSadovnychyi but can u please tell how?

Answer (score 4):

Simply closing the command prompt window and reopening it made it work. I don't know how or why.

Answer (score 0):

You may be mis-typing `appengine-try-python-flask` (the real name) as `appending-try-python-flask` (which is what you show in your question).

If that's not the case, can you please show the effects of `dir appengine-try-python-flask` and `dir appending-try-python-flask` from the directory (AKA folder) you're now trying to run `dev_appserver.py` from?

Answer (score 0):

probably you use py-charm, you need to add to configuration in line 'Working directory' the path of project like: C:\Users\user\Desktop\projects\water

It's repose to work[image]